# Lotus notes 8.5 'File not Found'

Tags: email, lotus-notes

I am trying to configure `Lotus Notes` after windows reinstall.

When I try to click on `Mail` I get error `File does not exist` and link that [redirects here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/search.wss?rs=475&tc=SSKTWP%20SSKTMJ&q=%22ERR_NOEXIST%22&dc=DA400%20DA100%20DA110%20DA120%20DA450%20DA300%20DB500&dtm).

[image]

When I try to get to `File > Preferences > Contacts.` ([as it is suggested here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21287201&context=SSKTWP%20SSKTMJ)) I get following error:

[image]

In `File > Locations > Manage Locations...` i get 4 locations but changing them does not seem to have any effect.

[image]

**console_48QZR12_2015_05_01@15_46_49.log** from (`C:\Users\[User]\AppData\Local\Lotus\Notes\Data\IBM_TECHNICAL_SUPPORT`)

```
console_48QZR12_2015_05_01@15_46_49.log
[0BE0:0002-1108] 01/05/2015 15:46:49.93 DeskClientOpenInt> Calling CreateProgramRCP pszRCPCmdLine[/authenticate ] bDeskProvisioningRestart [0]
[0BE0:0002-1108] 01/05/2015 15:46:49.93 DeskClientOpenInt> Executed CreateProgramRCP
[0918:0002-14F0] 01/05/2015 15:46:51.22 InitGlobalProcessInfo> PID [2328]!= [0]  
[095C:0002-0870] 01/05/2015 15:47:14   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[095C:0002-0870] 01/05/2015 15:47:14   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[095C:0002-0870] 01/05/2015 15:47:14   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[12B4:0002-10B8] 02/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[12B4:0002-10B8] 02/05/2015 03:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[12B4:0002-10B8] 02/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[1690:0004-0534:housekeeping] 02/05/2015 08:52:50   Housekeeping: Deleted 0 bookmark history records.
[0EA4:0002-11B4] 02/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[0EA4:0002-11B4] 02/05/2015 15:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[0EA4:0002-11B4] 02/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[1604:0002-0E00] 03/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[1604:0002-0E00] 03/05/2015 03:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[1604:0002-0E00] 03/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[1690:0004-0534:housekeeping] 03/05/2015 08:52:51   Housekeeping: Deleted 0 bookmark history records.
[163C:0002-0560] 03/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[163C:0002-0560] 03/05/2015 15:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[163C:0002-0560] 03/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[0BEC:0002-06D4] 04/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[0BEC:0002-06D4] 04/05/2015 03:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[0BEC:0002-06D4] 04/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[1690:0004-0534:housekeeping] 04/05/2015 08:52:52   Housekeeping: Deleted 0 bookmark history records.
[1530:0002-151C] 04/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[1530:0002-151C] 04/05/2015 15:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[1530:0002-151C] 04/05/2015 15:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
[1608:0002-16D8] 05/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration started
[1608:0002-16D8] 05/05/2015 03:47:15   Initializing Dynamic Client Configuration
[1608:0002-16D8] 05/05/2015 03:47:15   Dynamic Client Configuration shutdown
```

**Why is it failing? How do I fix it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit your Online location and check that the Mail file location and Mail file fields on the Mail tab are set (and point to a valid mail file).

Comment: When I switch to 'Local' Mail file location and try entering 'names.nsf' into Mail File field. I get message that I have to enter Domino mail domain.

Comment: names.nsf is your local address book and not your mail file. Your mai lfile should be on your mail server - most likely in the mail directory on the server.

Comment: So basically there's no way of solving this without admin.

Comment: There is indeed a way. You can look for your mail file on the mail server.

Comment: If you reinstalled, you probably don't have a local mail file created. You'll need to input your server and mail file path in the Online location document so it knows where to find your mail file. You could then recreate the local replica once it's able to open the server replica. If you don't know what your settings were before and didn't back anything up, you will definitely need someone from your organization that knows that stuff to help.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to re-run the Notes client setup procedure by cleaning out all but the first three lines of the notes.ini file and restarting the program. You can find further instructions for the procedure [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245069). (Note - it talks about moving several of other files out of the Notes\data folder and restoring them one at a time. It doesn't mention it, but you need to stop and restart the Notes client for each one.)